# Select multiple elements with multiple attributes (language switcher)

Tags: jquery, attributes, click

Why is `$('*[lang|="de"][lang|="sv"]').hide();` not selecting and then hiding all my h1s, h2s and ps with the lang="de" and lang="se" attributes? For example with

```
<p lang="de">Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Blindtext für die Druckindustrie.</p>
<p lang="en">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing industry.</p>
<p lang="sv">Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryckindustrin.</p>
```

I'm after a very simple triple language selector (English visible by default) like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('*[lang|="de"][lang|="sv"]').hide();

$("#lang_de").click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('*[lang|="en"][lang|="sv"]').hide();
$('*[lang|="de"]').show();
});

$("#lang_sv").click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('*[lang|="de"][lang|="en"]').hide();
$('*[lang|="sv"]').show();
});
</script>
```

Can attribute selectors not be combined this way?

**EDIT**: This works well for me now

```
(function () {
$('*[lang|="de"], *[lang|="sv"]').hide();

$("#lang_de").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('*[lang|="en"], *[lang|="sv"]').hide();
    $('*[lang|="de"]').show();
});

$("#lang_sv").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('*[lang|="de"], *[lang|="en"]').hide();
    $('*[lang|="sv"]').show();
});
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXEn4/2/)

You need to add a comma when having [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) in jQuery. It should look like

```
$('*[lang|="de"], *[lang|="sv"]').hide();
```

I have also made a fix to your click event.  It was not working either.  It too needs to be selected by the `*[lang|="de"]` call .  You can see a working example in jsfiddle.

Here is the jQuery documentation for [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Not exactly of your implematition of the language switcher.  However if you are looking for doing it for the whole site, instead of writing out your site multiple times in each language,  take a look at this post for [Multi Language](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.i18n.html) websites

** UPDATE **

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXEn4/3/) for not using the `*` as part of the selector

Comment: Thanks, the comma does the trick. I had indeed seen examples where multiple attributes were not comma separated; or maybe it was a class and an attribute that worked comma-less? Just out of interest - instead of using the dreaded universal selector (*) can one also specify a list of tags (say, h1 h2 p) in the same line?

Comment: When multiple attributes are not comma separated, that means, it is the element in the element.   Example `$('#test .this')` would get the element with class of this in the example   `<div id="test"><div class="this"></div></div><div class="this">but would not select this</div>`  Ass you can see it would select the `this` inside `test` but not the one outside.  see updated jsfiddle in a few minutes for example of non universal selector.

Comment: Ok, but what I put into my EDIT based on your input works well now. In the site's header, I got DE / EN / SE so one can select the desired language; subsequently all text is changed to the selected language and the DE / EN / SE in the header is removed.

Comment: Is there a question in that comment?

Comment: Nah, just browsed through that Zend stuff. For the simple company site I'm workin' on, doing it as above works well. Benefit is that the few bits and bobs o' text can be seen right next to each other in the markup - a benefit when having to constantly doing translations to English and German; y'know what I mean? Of course, on larger text-heavy sites, it would make sense to import the texts only when needed I guess.